# How to change facebook's user registration captcha test style?

Tags: facebook, recaptcha

I'm using facebook plugin for user registration on a website. 
I'm activating captcha by setting this field:

```
 {'name':'captcha'}
```

Everything works great, but I just don't like the look. Its too hardcore. I need to refresh it several times till I understand what's in the image.

So, is it possible to change the look to something more easier?

[image]

Comment: Guys, maybe there's a way to add some buttons? Like refresh and listen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses a system called reCaptcha to process captchas.  There is no way to change which system is uses.

Comment: I suspected that. Thanks Jordan!